# Voice SDK does not work on the Quest but does in Unity editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am making a VR game for the quest with Unity and for a trial I have a microphone with a button that you have to press and say a specific phrase. For that I am using the Voice SDK but I have a problem, it works in the editor but not once I compile and install the APK, I have the microphone permission so that is not the issue.

My `GameObject` that acts as a button is this:

[image: Microphone Button]

And the Microfono script is like this:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "dedo" && !triggerActivated)
    {
        triggerActivated = true;
        appVoice.Activate(GetRequestEvents());
     }
}
// Set the events for the Voice
private VoiceServiceRequestEvents GetRequestEvents()
{
    VoiceServiceRequestEvents events = new VoiceServiceRequestEvents();
    events.OnInit.AddListener(OnInit);
    events.OnComplete.AddListener(OnComplete);
    return events;
}
// What happens when the button is pressed
public void OnInit(VoiceServiceRequest request){
    micro.GetComponent<Outline>().enabled = false;
    verde.SetActive(true);
    rojo.SetActive(false);
}
// What happens when the transcription is complete
public void OnComplete(VoiceServiceRequest request){
    triggerActivated = false;
    verde.SetActive(false);
    rojo.SetActive(true);
}
```

The `OnTriggerEnter` method does work, I tried to place the `verde.SetActive(true);` before the `appVoice` activation and it did activate a green light when touching the microphone. Also the `GameObject` has a child `GameObject` with the response script (maybe it could go into the parent) like this:

[image: Response]

Any ideas why this might work on the editor and not on the Quest 3? It does not even launch the `OnInit` event because this line: `micro.GetComponent<Outline>().enabled = false;` should remove the outline around the object and it does not work.

Some info that I forgot and may be useful, I use Meta XR All-in-One SDK version 62 and Unity 2022.3